# Return on no text in UISearchbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchbar that has the return key on the keyboard that is greyed out unless I type text into the searchbar. How do I allow it to appear on no text? If thats not possible, how do I return to my view if theres no text in the searchbar?

Heres some code:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
touchtoCancel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-211)];

[touchtoCancel addTarget:self
                action:@selector(DidPressCancelSearch:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.search setFrame:CGRectMake(self.search.frame.origin.x, self.search.frame.origin.y-210,
                                      self.search.frame.size.width, self.search.frame.size.height)];
return YES;
}


-(IBAction)DidPressCancelSearch:(id)sender
{
    [search resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: You can use a built in cancel button with the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method besides the built-in cancel button that was already mentioned... You can create an invisible button that takes up the area above the keyboard which enables only when editing the search bar. Tapping on this invisible button (space between search bar and top of the keyboard) should resign the first responder.

Comment: I have added the invisible button, and added a function that calls [mysearch resignFirstResponder]; They are connected using the addTarget: action: etc method. For some reason it isn't working. I have confirmed that the invisible button exists. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Place some NSLogs to ensure that the function you are expecting to be called are actually being called. Also, why is the return type of DidPressCancelSearch: an IBAction? Change it to void since you are specifying it programmatically and don't want any conflicts with a xib file.

Comment: It turns out I had forgotten to add the button to the subview. Rookie mistake. Thanks!